# Jssor Slider captions start all together

Tags: jssor

Have a look [at this demo](http://www.jssor.com/demos/introduction-slider.html). As you can see captions are being animated one after another. Is is possible to have all the captions start together but with specific delay. Like

1. Caption 1 after 100 milliseconds
2. Caption 2 after 500 milliseconds
3. Caption 3 after 800 milliseconds

I know all the animations can be flattened by using `$PlayInMode: 1` in config but that doesn't do the trick I'm looking for. I was looking for an option like slider revolution [in this example](http://themepunch.com/revolution/home-slider-fullscreen). Notice that all the animation elements do not come one after another. There are overlaps. It's like animation in multiple layers in a timeline in flash.

Anyone has any idea if this can be achieved by jssor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use b attribute to specify begin time for caption animation.

```
<div u="caption" t="transition-1" b="100" ...>...</div>
<div u="caption" t="transition-2" b="500" ...>...</div>
<div u="caption" t="transition-3" b="800" ...>...</div>


b:  a numeric value (in milliseconds) indicates an explicit begin time to start
    animation. By default, captions play in one by one. But if a caption specified
    with 'b' explicitly, it breaks the streamline.
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html

Also, if you want to play caption one by one, but overlap sometimes, you can use d attribute.

```
<div u="caption" t="transition-1" ...>...</div>
<div u="caption" t="transition-2" d="-300" ...>...</div>
<div u="caption" t="transition-3" ...>...</div>
```

The code above enables the 2nd caption start 300 milliseconds before the end of 1st caption.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So `$PlayInMode: 3` and using b="{{millioseond}}" does the trick.